# Cannot interact with DIV via jQuery after it is destroyed and recreated?

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout

## Problem

After it has been destroyed and recreated, I can no longer interact with a DIV on my site.  I have tried using both its ID and class, with no luck.

## To reproduce

Go to http://new.element17.com.  Click the `Photo Grid` button in the far bottom-right.  Then click one of the thumbnails.  That photo should load and the photo grid should fade out.

Now click `Albums` up at the top, and select any album.  Click the `Photo Grid` button again, and click one of the thumbnails.  That photo should load but the photo grid will not fade out.

## Code

The grid itself is created by the [Cycle 2 plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) and is destroyed whenever the album is changed, then recreated.

It by itself looks like this:

`<div id="photo_grid" class="photo_grid_class"></div>`

The jQuery for the thumbnails looks like this:

```
$('.grid_thumb').click(function() {
  $('#grid').addClass('fadein').removeClass('active');
  $('.photo_grid_class').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

How can I make it so that even after it is destroyed and recreated, I can still interact with this DIV?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$('.grid_thumb').click(function() {
```

To

```
$(document).on('click', '.grid_thumb', function() {
```

Should work.

Comment: Or better yet, some deeper static parent element in place of `document`.  Check out the event delegation section of the `on` documentation`.  http://api.jquery.com/on/